# SELECT to continuous tables with the same data types

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that looks like this:

```
TermID | Term | Doc1|Doc2|..|Doc998 |

1      | tag  | 3   | 0  |..| 5     |
```

Because the number of documents is beyond the limitation of column number in Mysql I have created other tables for different documents. The third table has a different number of columns.

I want to select each row of these 3 tables to compute the values of its cell. The problem is how to use SELECT continuously from table 1-3 since they have different number of columns.

Comment: This data model is literally across the lines of relational model design. Consider converting to a structure with a `doc_id` column instead. You will have one well-behaved table. The problem will become trivial.

Comment: ^Still not a good design. Then the users will come in columns. What needs to be done is a separate table for users, another for docs and a third relation between user and docs.

Comment: I have used Doc_ID in columns and in rows I use the 'words' or terms. Actually I am doing this to index documents. But I'm confused now.

Comment: @krisna What they are saying is that you need only 1 column `DocID`, not 998.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION`

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
WHERE conditions

UNION ALL

SELECT col3, col4
FROM table2
WHERE conditions

UNION ALL

SELECT col5, col6
FROM table3
WHERE conditions
```

However, as stated in the comments, this is a REALLY bad design. You could replace your schema with a `Document` table and a `Term` table, using a foreign key to link them.

Comment: I have a document table with Doc_ID, but I don't have a Term table. Do you mean that I need to create the Term table, then?

Comment: I don't think `Union` will work in this case; cause as OP stated all his 3 tables have different number of columns.

Comment: @krisna Yes, you need 2 tables. You should read up on relational database modeling.

Comment: @Union yes it will, UNION ALL merges all columns.